# XQuery insert/update value

Tags: sql, xquery

I want to update xml like this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Properties xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <BackupPath>MyLocalPath</BackupPath>
</Properties>
```

using stored procedure

```
declare @PropertyName       nvarchar(500)
declare @PropertyValue      nvarchar(MAX)

set @PropertyName = 'BackupPath'
set @PropertyValue = 'MyTestPath'

DECLARE @ExistingSettings XML;
DECLARE @NewSettings nvarchar(MAX);

SET @ExistingSettings = (SELECT TOP(1) CAST(SettingsDefinition  AS XML) FROM ApplicationSettings)

SET @ExistingSettings.modify('replace value of (/Properties/*[local-name() = sql:variable("@PropertyName")]/text())[1] with sql:variable("@PropertyValue")')

UPDATE ApplicationSettings
SET SettingsDefinition = CAST(@ExistingSettings AS nvarchar(MAX)), LastUpdate = GetDate()
WHERE ID = (SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM ApplicationSettings)
```

and this works fine as long as 'BackupPath' contains value

```
<BackupPath>MyLocalPath</BackupPath>
```

How to modify this query to insert value (or validate if needed) if

```
<BackupPath />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't require a text node in your XPath.

```
SET @ExistingSettings.modify(
  'replace value of (/Properties/' + @PropertyName + ')[1] with sql:variable("@PropertyValue")'
)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message now. The argument 1 of the XML data type method "modify" must be a string literal.

Comment: By any chance, does this approach work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21457475/18771